# Getting No bean resolver registered

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

After upgrading today from `Spring boot 1.2.5` to `1.3.0 BUILD-SNAPSHOT` Calling
`@PreAuthorize` fails:

example:

```
@PreAuthorize("@defaultSecurityService.canDoSomething(authentication.principal.id, #objId)")
Result doSomething(@P("objId")String objId);
```

where `defaultSecurityService` is defined as:

```
@Service
public class DefaultSecurityService implements SecurityService {
    ...
    public boolean canDoSomething(String userId, String objId){
        return true; // 
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.throwOnError(defaultSecurityService.canDoSomething(authentication.principal.id, #objId))'
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:14)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 8): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'defaultSecurityService'
```

**what i've tried:**

make `SecurityService` extend [PermissionEvaluator`][1] and register a bean 
at`Application.java`

```
 @Bean
 @Lazy
 public PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator(){
     return securityService;
 }`
```

But i'm still getting the same error

Reading the spring security 4.0.2 documentation didn't reveal any relevant material about breaking changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3542) in the newly added [OAuth2AutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/db41e0d7d5cd120892df8f7196021f0c35ec9136/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/OAuth2AutoConfiguration.java). Specifically it brings in [OAuth2MethodSecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/db41e0d7d5cd120892df8f7196021f0c35ec9136/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/method/OAuth2MethodSecurityConfiguration.java) which overrides the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` with a `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` that does not have a `BeanResolver` set.

If you are not using OAuth2, then the easiest solution is to remove Spring Security OAuth from your classpath.

Alternatively, you can exclude the `OAuth2AutoConfiguration` using the following if you use `@SpringBootApplication`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=OAuth2AutoConfiguration.class)
```

alternatively you can use the following if you leverage `@AutoConfiguration` directly:

```java
@AutoConfiguration(exclude=OAuth2AutoConfiguration.class)
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use something like this:

```java
public class DelegatingMethodSecurityExpressionHandler implements
        MethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    private final MethodSecurityExpressionHandler delegate;

    public DelegatingMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(
            MethodSecurityExpressionHandler delegate) {
        super();
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Object filter(Object filterTarget, Expression filterExpression,
            EvaluationContext ctx) {
        return delegate.filter(filterTarget, filterExpression, ctx);
    }

    public ExpressionParser getExpressionParser() {
        return delegate.getExpressionParser();
    }

    public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(
            Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        return delegate.createEvaluationContext(authentication, invocation);
    }

    public void setReturnObject(Object returnObject, EvaluationContext ctx) {
        delegate.setReturnObject(returnObject, ctx);
    }
}
```

Then in your configuration use:

```java
@Autowired(required = false)
List<AuthenticationTrustResolver> trustResolvers = new ArrayList<>();

@Autowired(required = false)
List<PermissionEvaluator> permissionEvaluators = new ArrayList<>();

@Bean
public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler securityExpressionHandler(ApplicationContext context) {
    OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler delegate = new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    delegate.setApplicationContext(context);
    if(trustResolvers.size() == 1) {
        delegate.setTrustResolver(trustResolvers.get(0));
    }
    if(permissionEvaluators.size() == 1) {
        delegate.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluators.get(0));
    }
    return new DelegatingMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(delegate);
}
```

We have to wrap it in the DelegatingMethodSecurityExpressionHandler because Spring Boot's auto config will replace any subclass of `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` with the broken configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rob. I use oauth2 extensively...is there any other way?

Comment: I did figure out another workaround. See the UPDATE section.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem than you, my bean in charge of managing security on a REST controller wasn't found:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 8): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'communitySecurityAuthorizer
```

Rob's reply pointed me in the right direction (I thought I was doing it wrong, not that it was a bug in the standard Spring OAuth2).

I don't use springboot as I'm making a webapp and I found the answer that solved my problem here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/730#issuecomment-219480394

The problem comes in fact from the bean resolver which is null so here is the solution (retranscription of the link above):

Add a @Bean with OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler that explicitly
    sets the application context

```
@Bean
    public OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler oAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
```

In the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, configure the resources and
    pass in the Bean above.

```
@Autowired
    private OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler;
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.expressionHandler(expressionHandler);
    }
```

Hope this'll others !

Comment: This helped, thank you. Apparently they fixed `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, but for `OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler` the issue persists.

Comment: I've added comment to closed issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3542

Answer (score 1):

As Almiriad has said, generate the `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` instance as a bean.

Instead do that:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
             return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

        ....
}
```

do this:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
             return getOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler getOAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
             return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

        ....
}
```

Hope this'll others !